# How to display an image chosen by a file open picker in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, image, uwp, path, fileopenpicker

I implemented a File Open Picker into a Universal Windows Platform Application for choosing an image to display in a list item.

However, after getting the image path from the file open picker, the path can't be set as an image source neither as a URI nor network path (tried "file:///" + path).

**Is there a way to show an image from a file open picker selected path?**

**If not, is there any way to open a local image from the computer in the app?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I implemented a File Open Picker into a Universal Windows Platform Application for choosing an image to display in a list item.

UWP does not support `file://` uri scheme, if you open the file with file open picker, you could open the file as stream, and convert it to `BitmapImage` like the following.

```
try
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
    {
        ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
        SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    };
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;

        }
    }
   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: A performance consideration with this: MyImage.Source should be set *before* calling SetSourceAsync, to allow the XAML framework to decode the image to correct render size.